# Ubuntu keeps looping back to login screen

Tags: login

I was half way through an update and needed to stop the download and switched my computer off (Dell latitude E6500) (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS). Now the screen keeps looping back to login after I enter my password. Help please!!

Answer (score 0):

Bring the grub menu up as you boot (usually with shift or esc if it doesn't come automatically) and go to `Advanced Options for Ubuntu`. Then, choose:

`dpkg     Repair Broken packages`

or choose

`root     Drop to root shell prompt`

and execute the commands:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -f`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Hi! This brings me to a screen which only offers generic recovery mode (s)

Comment: Is it possible you add me on fb and we video chat ... Pleeeeeeeeaaaseee?!